# Check image quality in flutter

Tags: flutter, image-optimization, image-quality

I am building an app where the user can pick multiple images and I lay all the images out in a gallery view. I need to show an i icon on the images that has very low quality. Now my question is that how do I check the quality of the image in flutter ?

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, there's no built-in way to directly check the quality of an image. However, you can infer the quality of an image by checking its resolution or size. A high-resolution image is generally considered to be of high quality. Here's a simple way to check the resolution of an image:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

Future<ui.Image> _getImage(String path) async {
  final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
  final File imgFile = File(path);
  final ui.ImageCodec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(imgFile.readAsBytesSync());
  final ui.FrameInfo frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();
  return frameInfo.image;
}

void checkImageQuality() async {
  final ui.Image image = await _getImage('assets/images/my_image.jpg');
  final int height = image.height;
  final int width = image.width;

  if (height * width < 200 * 200) {
    print('Low quality image');
  } else {
    print('High quality image');
  }
}
```

In this code, _getImage function reads an image file and returns a ui.Image object. The checkImageQuality function then checks the resolution of the image. If the resolution is less than 200x200, it's considered low quality.

Please note that this is a very basic way to check image quality. The quality of an image can be subjective and depends on various factors like compression, color depth, bit rate, etc. If you need a more sophisticated way to check image quality, you might need to use a machine learning model or a third-party service

Comment: You should also check that the ratio bits/pixel is reasonable. You can have a high quality tiny image that should not be faulted as well as massive large images that have been badly over compressed. A crude heuristic for JPEG is that 4Mpixel/MB or if you prefer 2 bits per pixel is an acceptable threshold for a good quality image without obvious artefacts (but there will always be exceptions to any simple heuristic rule). Only the OP can decide what he considers an acceptable quality/size tradeoff.